# qvtkwidget interaction with a slider

Tags: qt, connection, slider, vtk

I have a problem with qvtkwidget. I have a cube with the vtkimageplanewidget and i already made the connection between the sliders and them, but I want the slider to change also when I change the planes with the mouse in the qvtkwidget.

How can i do that?

Here's how I connected the slider eith the planes.

SLOT:

```
void planevolume::SplaneXpixel()
{
    double xvalue=ui->Slider->value();
    planeX->SetSliceIndex(xvalue);
    ui->qvtkWidget->update();
}
```

and then:

```
  connect(ui->Slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)), this, SLOT(SplaneXpixel()));
```

What about the opposite? I tried:

SLOT:

```
void planevolume::planeXSpixel()
{
    double xvalue=planeX->GetSliceIndex();
    ui->Slider->setValue(xvalue);
    ui->qvtkWidget->update();
}
```

and then:

```
connect(ui->qvtkWidget, SIGNAL(mouseEvent(QMouseEvent*)), SLOT(planeXSpixel()));
```

but it won't work, can anyone help me?

Comment: What won't work? I'd suggest posting a fully compilable example, and explaining what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for vtkEventQtSlotConnect. Here is an example:
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Qt/EventQtSlotConnect

Answer (score 0):

If you work with the UI form, right click the slider, choose "Go to slot..." and select the sliderMoved(int) slot.
Inside the automated slot created by Qt, it should be on_slider_sliderMoved(int position).
just insert your code there.
maybe this implementation should help you further:

[Displaying DICOM Series using the Qt sliderbar](http://hxr99.blogspot.com/2013/03/qt-vtk-displaying-dicom-series-using.html)